# Projecting grid textures to select parts of the terrain (Unity)

Tags: unity, shaders, textures, terrain, grid

So I'm trying to be smart and not use 500+ some tile prefabs to make a grid, and so far the back-end portion has gone swimmingly. I initially used a dedicated mesh to represent the grid, but as I'm now opting for 3D terrain (and not tilemapping), I figured that was a lot of unnecessary vertices - especially if I want to have the grid conform to the terrain.

My shader inexperience, on the other hand, is causing me to stop and overthink this.

[image: FE Awakening]

Using FE as inspiration, I'm thinking about projecting the transparent grid texture onto a base terrain layer.

- If I wanted parts of the terrain to not be covered by the grid (such as the water area in the picture), would I simply use the world coordinates to tell the shader don't do anything there?

The most confusing part for me, however, is how to go about highlighting tiles. I want movement and attack tiles to also be 'painted' onto the terrain in specific colors, but obviously they only affect an even smaller portion than the terrain than the grid.

- Would I simply be using the same shader to grab world coordinates once again and more or less start/stop overlaying the movement/attack texture over the grid/terrain? And if I'm really being efficient, those textures belong to the same png and I just use UV's to switch between them like a sprite sheet?
- Is this even a good practice for shaders in the first place? Redrawing and adding textures to only parts of a material? Should I be redrawing and updating the whole texture instead?

I guess I get thrown off because I'm only familiar with a 1:1 mesh to material design, so the so the thought of a single mesh but multiple textures on discrete parts that may or may not overlap makes somewhat sense on paper -- but implementation in Unity is just above me atm.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't matter one jot what "they" are doing. If you think the method you've thought of might work for your case, then try it! If you don't know how, ask about the specific step you don't know how to do. Right now every sentence in your post that ends with a question mark is about somebody else's game - we have no indication of where specifically you're stuck in your attempt to apply this to *your* game.

Comment: You're right, I have no intention of replicating their implementation, just their end result. Hope the rewording makes it more clear.